# CSS Menu - submenu disappearing

Tags: css, submenu

The submenu under story.php shows fine on the index.php and story.php pages.  When I hover over story.php link from any other page (joinus.php, events.php, shop.php), the submenu shows but then disappears when I try to click on any of the submenu items.

```
<ul id="navbar" class="drop">
    <li><a href="story.php">ABOUT US</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="storynav" href="story.php">OUR STORY</a></li>
            <li><a id="meetusnav" href="meetus.php">MEET US</a></li>
            <li><a id="valuesnav" href="values.php">MISSION & VALUES</a></li>
            <li><a id="faqnav" href="faq.php">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a id="contactnav" href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="joinusnav" href="joinus.php">JOIN US</a></li>
    <li><a id="eventsnav" href="events.php">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a id="shopnav" href="shop.php">SHOP</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    width: 600px;
}

.drop {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
    float: left;
}

.drop a {
    display: block;
    font: bold 15px verdana;
    color: #383838;
    text-align: center;
    textshadow: 0 1px 3px #808080;
}

.drop li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.drop ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
}

.drop li ul:hover, .drop li ul.hover {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    z index: 599;
    cursor: default;
}

.drop ul a {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.drop li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I don't know if this is affecting anything, but I also have this css:

```
body#home a#homenav, body#story a#storynav, body#meetus a#meetusnav, 
body#values a#valuesnav, body#faq a#faqnav, body#contact a#contactnav,
body#joinus a#joinusnav, body#events a#eventsnav, body#shop a#shopnav {
    border-bottom: 3px groove #909090;
}

body#story .drop ul, body#meetus .drop ul, body#values .drop ul, 
body#faq .drop ul, body#contact .drop ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:  I finally figured it out.  It was due to the last bit of CSS {border-bottom:3px groove #909090} to highlight the current page/link.  That was causing a 3px gap between the anchor and submenu.  I added border-bottom:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0) to .drop a and that solved the problem.  I don't know if this is the right way, but it is working for me now so I will go with it.

Comment: I Have made a fiddle for you [http://jsfiddle.net/vals/pRSAs/]. It works ok for me - besides being rather ugly :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest it's a z-index property somewhere, either that or your rule of "visibility: visible". I don't really know without a jsfiddle.

Otherwise, I would check what's different between the files. '[DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)' is a cool tool to quickly see differences between files.

It might be quicker just to [steal a menu](http://cssmenumaker.com/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a z-index problem, personaly i always put menus on absolute and gives them some '9' in the z-index, try to check if you have any absolute position close to this menu 
Anyway heres my old css menu:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul id="mainm">
<li class="clas">Home<ul><li class="cc">Header 1</li><li class="dd">Header 2</li><li class="cc">Header 3</li><li class="dd">Header 4</li><li class="cc">Header 5</li>
<li id="bottomend"  class="dd">Header 6</li></ul></li>
<li class="clas">About<ul><li class="cc">Header 1</li><li class="dd">Header 2</li><li class="cc">Header 3</li><li class="dd">Header 4</li><li class="cc">Header 5</li><li id="bottomend" class="dd">Header 6</li></ul></li>
<li class="clas">FAQ<ul><li class="cc">Header 1</li><li class="dd">Header 2</li><li class="cc">Header 3</li><li class="dd">Header 4</li><li class="cc">Header 5</li><li id="bottomend" class="dd">Header 6</li></ul></li>
<li class="clas">Site Design's<ul><li class="cc">Header 1</li><li class="dd">Header 2</li><li class="cc">Header 3</li><li class="dd">Header 4</li><li class="cc">Header 5</li><li id="bottomend" class="dd">Header 6</li></ul></li>
<li class="clas" id="boright">Sign Up !<ul><li class="cc">Header 1</li><li class="dd">Header 2</li><li class="cc">Header 3</li><li class="dd">Header 4</li><li class="cc">Header 5</li><li id="bottomend" class="dd">Header 6</li></ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

style :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
    font-family: 'Mr Dafoe', cursive;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;

     }
    body { font-family:'Fjalla One'; color:#fff}
#mainm{list-style-type:none; text-align: center;}
.clas ul { list-style-type:none; padding:0px;display:none; background-color:#903; }

.clas { float:left; width:90px; background-color:#2872DF;  border:0px; height:30px; font-family:'Fjalla One'; font-weight:300; line-height:30px; 
    border-left:1px solid #7C99E4;
         background: rgb(59,103,158); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%, rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(59,103,158,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(43,136,217,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b679e', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
#boright {border-right:1px solid #7C99E4;}
.main:hover {background-color:#78A3F1;}
.clas:hover {background-color:#78A3F1;
background: rgb(126,204,234); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(126,204,234,1) 0%, rgba(11,176,226,1) 50%, rgba(121,206,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(126,204,234,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(11,176,226,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(121,206,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(126,204,234,1) 0%,rgba(11,176,226,1) 50%,rgba(121,206,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(126,204,234,1) 0%,rgba(11,176,226,1) 50%,rgba(121,206,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(126,204,234,1) 0%,rgba(11,176,226,1) 50%,rgba(121,206,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(126,204,234,1) 0%,rgba(11,176,226,1) 50%,rgba(121,206,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7eccea', endColorstr='#79ceea',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}


.clas:hover ul { display:block; border:0px solid black; width:120px; height:180px; line-height:30px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color:#78A3F1; margin-top:0px;}
.imgfl {float:right; top: 70px; box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #003;  margin-right:70px;}
li ul li.cc {background-color:#78A3F1; width:150px; text-align:center; border-bottom: 3px #7C99E4 solid;}
 li ul li.dd {background-color:#5582D5; width:150px; text-align:center; border-bottom: 3px #7C99E4 solid;}
 li ul .cc:hover , .dd:hover  {background-color:#F96;}
#bottomend {  border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
#border { position:absolute; border:2px solid #FFF; width:200px; height:200px; z-index:20;}
#clas:hover ul{ 
    display:block; 
    border:0px solid black; 
    width:300px; height:150px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    padding:00px 0px 0px 00px; 
    background-color:#78A3F1; 
    margin-top:0px;
}
#menu {  
    height:30px; 
             box-shadow:5px 1px 5px #666;
    width:700px;
    padding:0px 160px;
    background: rgb(59,103,158); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%, rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(59,103,158,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(43,136,217,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b679e', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```